# Character "|" in sms

Tags: java, android

I programmly send sms message with "|" in string, and receiving it android make it unreadable. Can I make something with this?
Thanks.

Comment: "Can I make something with this?" --> what do you mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.csoft.co.uk/sms/character_sets/gsm.htm) an overview on the GSM 03.38 character set. As I understand it, you have to send the `<ESC>` char before `|`. And there are some more characters that have to be escaped.

Answer (score -1):

we can use ascii value of |, from http://www.asciitable.com/.

Comment: No you can't. GSM doesn't use ASCII, see GSM standard 03.38